# is it possible to add Google Tag Manager to both head and body

Tags: javascript, magento, head, google-tag-manager, document-body

I would like to leverage GTM more. I have it set it up and working with all tags inside the `<head>`. Is it possible to have it 2 containers, 1 for  and 1 for , and then add all scripts in each relevant container? Is there any other way accomplish this.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have multiple GTM containers on the one page.

You would have to rename `dataLayer` to something else on the 2nd one to avoid conflicts.